# Amplify Storage, put public files

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I'm uploading to an S3 bucket some file, with:

```
const { key } = await Storage.put(filename, file, {
  contentType: 'image/jpeg',
  level: 'public'
});
```

The 3rd parameter sets the `config` of the `put()` method, which the documentation says:

```
@param {Object} [config] - { level : private|protected|public, contentType: MIME Types,
 *  progressCallback: function }
```

But each upload file is being created as privated. I already set as public the entire folder, but I don't know how to create public files too.